# Android Studio - Clicklistener on any button?

Tags: android, android-studio

So I'm still learning Android Studio and I'm trying to muddle my way through making a simple whack-a-mole type game.  A grid of 9 buttons are hidden and when one button is clicked a random number generator set an int variable which then goes through a switch which sets the visibility of the next button.

This has been fine until I want to add +1 to a score int.  Each button has it's own clicklistener with it's own (very inefficient of course) copy of the switch and if statement checking whether it's already visible etc and I can't get them all to update the same variable as it needs to be declared final but when I do it just says cannot assign variable.

So is it possible to do a something like a clicklistener on ANY button rather than a specific one?  Then I could define and update the variable in that one method (if that's the right terminology).

Here's a quick copy of what the first button looks like which is visible until first clicked -

```
button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            button0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Random rand = new Random();
            int n = rand.nextInt(9);

            switch (n) {
                case 0:
                    if(button0.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                        button0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else{
                        button0.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                    break; ... and so on
```

And so what I'd like is something like this (that obviously works) -

```
    button0 or button1 or button2 or button3 or button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int scoreint = 0;
            scoreint++;
            scoreText.setText(""+scoreint);  
        };
```

Like I said, I know this is the most inefficient and slowest way of doing things but I'm still learning and like doing things the simplest, stupidest way so I can get the core concepts.  I am watching tutorials too but I like a little side project to get into too.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: yes it is possible, and you check v.getId() against the id of each single button to understand which one you clicked

Comment: Cool thanks for the reply, another answer has said a similar thing so it's given me something to look into - thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hop this pease of code helps you

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  implements View.OnClickListener{



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button0);
    button0.setOnClickListener(this);

    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);

    //and on ....
    }

 public void onClick(View view)
{
     switch (view.getId())
     {
         case R.id.button0 :
        // do sum thing 
          break;
         case R.id.button1 :
        // do sum thing 
          break;
     }

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer and some sample code, it's really helpful.  I never thought of using another switch on the buttons themselves, I still have one problem though.  I'm getting "cannot resolve symbol" errors on the buttons and int variable within the switch code.  This goes away when I define my int variable within the onClick, but not when I move the buttons too.  I must be missing something somewhere :/

Comment: i think you need  to use the score int as a global variable because if it is in the switch the score int is out of scope try this and let me know

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although I know the theory I've never needed to mess with different variables, but moving my int outside of onCreate lets me access it.  Still no luck with my buttons though.  They're declared within onCreate but can't be resolved from inside the onClick.  In fact when I declare the buttons inside the onClick it still says cannot resolve so maybe the problem is with my switch case rather than where I've declared the buttons.

Comment: Actually I might've solved it myself - my button id is (for example) Button0 with a capital B but when declaring them (again if that's the right terminology) I do Button button0 ... R.id.Button0; so I've been referencing the wrong id for the same button.  I think this programming stuff might be starting to sink in lol