# how to get id of automatically button in android?

Tags: java, android, button

first i am verry sorry about my english.
i have a code like this

```
int id = 1;
for(Objet obj: arrObj){
     Button btn = new Button(this);
     btn.setText(obj.get_NameObj().toString());
     btn.setId(id);
     btn.setOnClickListenner(this);
     LinearLayout linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
     linear.addView(btn);
     id++;
```

a list of button will be created depend on size of `arrObj`. now how can i get Id or some way to use of those button to use in onClick(View arg) function. because when i click any button i need put some data depend on that button to another activity?.

for example.

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // that is not worked. so any way to do this
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case 1:
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ManagerListActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("btn_value", "btn_one");
        startActivity(i);
        break;

    case 2:
        Intent ii = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ManagerListActivity.class);
        ii.putExtra("btn_value", "btn_two");
        startActivity(ii);
        break;

        //.......here depending on size of arrObj
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

i tried to `setOnClickListenner` inside the `createButton` function, it worked but the data pass to another activity is only the data of the last button has been created for all the button i clicked.

any way to do that.

thank you to listening.

pls tell me if you dont understant what i meant.

Comment: here i dont know how many button was created. it depent on arrObj

Comment: hi check this out    Android Studio - Clicklistener on any button?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199139/android-studio-clicklistener-on-any-button/33199574#33199574

Comment: it not working for my case.